# SQL foreign key implementation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys

I must create university database tables on `SQL`.

I have three tables:

> university, faculty and department

All of them have primary keys `id`.

So when I create department table must I add there foreign keys of `university` and `faculty` table or only faculty id is enough ?

And which type of key I must use for id ?  Primary or unique ? I don't understand their difference well.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hierarchy is `university -> faculty -> department`, then you put the `university_id` in the faculty table and `faculty_id` in the department table.

A `primary key` is a combination of a `unique constraint` and a `not null constraint` (and the ordering of the physical table).

Comment: There's also a semantic meaning to the primary key, in that it is considered to be the authoritative identifying value for the table's row. It should also be immutable (ie. never changing), which is not the case for a unique key.

A unique key could also have a not null constraint on it. A good example is that you might provide a unique key with not null constraint to define the sorting order for rows in a table. That can of course change, and would not usually be considered to be an identifier of the row.

Answer (score 1):

The three tables university,faculty and department have primary key that uniquely identifies each row in that table. To have relation between each table there should be a foreign key relation.

The difference between primary key and unique constraint is that primary key does not allow NULL values but there can be one NULL value as unique key. Both of them uniquely identifies each row in a table and does not allow duplicates.